# ANR in com.xxx message what does it mean

Tags: android

I have an app that runs ok in one device but in another device I get the following in my logcat:

```
    01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819): ANR in com.tfl.extprotocolservice
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819): PID: 4516
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819): Reason: Executing service com.tfl.extprotocolservice/.ExtProtocolService
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819): Load: 2.01 / 2.07 / 2.08
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819): CPU usage from 9304ms to 0ms ago:
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819):   0.3% 4516/com.tfl.extprotocolservice: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 353 minor
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819):   0.2% 1819/system_server: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819):   0.2% 1877/com.android.systemui: 0.2% user + 0% kernel
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819):   0.1% 1459/surfaceflinger: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819):   0.1% 1470/adbd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819):   0.1% 1541/ksdioirqd/mmc1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819): 0.4% TOTAL: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819): CPU usage from 1978ms to 2491ms later:
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819):   13% 1819/system_server: 3.9% user + 9.8% kernel
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819):     7.8% 1835/android.bg: 0% user + 7.8% kernel
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819):     1.9% 1819/system_server: 1.9% user + 0% kernel
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819):     1.9% 1834/ActivityManager: 1.9% user + 0% kernel
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819):   2.8% 991/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 2.8% kernel
01-02 02:42:16.800: E/ActivityManager(1819): 4.2% TOTAL: 0.5% user + 3.7% kernel
```

on my screen nothing appears , no error message , nothing. 
what does it mean ?

Comment: is it showing dialog ?

Comment: @Nilesh nothing is showing on screen that's the weird part

Comment: can you post your code so we can get reson ?

Comment: Probably you are blocking the main thread, doing computations which take time. Consider creating a thread which is going to do the computations which are currently done in the main thread.

You can see link http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: When the main thread is blocked in a Service, the ANR is reported with the logcat messages instead of a dialog.  See this [related issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981433/why-i-am-getting-this-error-for-service). `extprotocolservice`  is doing too much work on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

ANR stands for "App Not Responding" and it means that the app has blocked for too long on the UI thread.

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr).